# A function in R for "joining"/"concantenating" word lists

Tags: r, string, list, sum, concatenation

A function in R for "summing" word lists, example:

```
A = list (c ("Flower", "Car"), "Moto")
B = list ("Blue", c ("Black", "Red"))
```

And the result is C

```
C = list (c ("Flower", "Car", "Blue"), c ("Moto", "Black", "Red"))
```

Please help me

Answer (score 2):

You can do: `do.call(Map, c(c, list(A, B)))`
The same with `purrr`:

```
purrr::map2(A,B,c)

[[1]]
[1] "Flower" "Car"    "Blue"  

[[2]]
[1] "Moto"  "Black" "Red"
```

Comment: Edited to add "my answer". Hope that's OK with you.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base R solution similar to the answer by [@YOLO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59577199/12158757)

```
C <- Map(c,A,B)
```

or using `mapply()`

```
C <- mapply(c,A,B,SIMPLIFY = F)
```

such that

```
> C
[[1]]
[1] "Flower" "Car"    "Blue"  

[[2]]
[1] "Moto"  "Black" "Red"
```